# Visual Studio 2015 Community - XAML Desginer extremely slow to load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create a WPF application, but when I open up the XAML designer view I get an exception which points to the ActivityLog.xml file.  The error entry is show here:

```
  <entry>
    <record>433</record>
    <time>2015/11/30 13:50:43.147</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>.NET Framework Version: 4.0.40305.0</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>434</record>
    <time>2015/11/30 13:50:43.147</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>MSXML Version: 6.30.7601.18923</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>435</record>
    <time>2015/11/30 13:50:47.206</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Searching folder for extension.vsixmanifest files...</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>436</record>
    <time>2015/11/30 13:50:47.262</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Extension is enabled...</description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\1DSTIDTC.LPJ\</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>437</record>
    <time>2015/11/30 13:54:46.274</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.NotSupportedException: Required  Service &apos;ITypeResolverService&apos; not found.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.HostServices.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type serviceType)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlFileInformationService.CreateFileInformationContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.EnsureBufferCache(IVsTextLines textLines)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.EnsureBufferCache(IVsTextView view)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlSource.BeginParse(Int32 line, Int32 idx, TokenInfo info, ParseReason reason, IVsTextView view, ParseResultHandler callback)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.ViewFilter.GetDataTipText(TextSpan[] aspan, String&amp; textValue)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.TryGetQuickInfoFromFilter(IQuickInfoSession session, TextSpan[] dataBufferTextSpan, String&amp; tipText)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.AugmentQuickInfoSession(IQuickInfoSession session, IList`1 qiContent, ITrackingSpan&amp; applicableToSpan)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Recalculate()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Start()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.DefaultQuickInfoController.OnTextView_MouseHover(Object sender, MouseHoverEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.RaiseHoverEvents()</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>438</record>
    <time>2015/11/30 13:54:51.921</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.NotSupportedException: Required  Service &apos;ITypeResolverService&apos; not found.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.HostServices.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type serviceType)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlFileInformationService.CreateFileInformationContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.EnsureBufferCache(IVsTextLines textLines)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.EnsureBufferCache(IVsTextView view)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlSource.BeginParse(Int32 line, Int32 idx, TokenInfo info, ParseReason reason, IVsTextView view, ParseResultHandler callback)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.ViewFilter.GetDataTipText(TextSpan[] aspan, String&amp; textValue)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.TryGetQuickInfoFromFilter(IQuickInfoSession session, TextSpan[] dataBufferTextSpan, String&amp; tipText)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.AugmentQuickInfoSession(IQuickInfoSession session, IList`1 qiContent, ITrackingSpan&amp; applicableToSpan)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Recalculate()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Start()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.DefaultQuickInfoController.OnTextView_MouseHover(Object sender, MouseHoverEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.RaiseHoverEvents()</description>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

Here is the exception details by itself:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Required  Service &apos;ITypeResolverService&apos; not found.&#x000D;&#x000A; 
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.HostServices.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type serviceType)&#x000D;&#x000A;
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlFileInformationService.CreateFileInformationContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)&#x000D;&#x000A;
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.EnsureBufferCache(IVsTextLines textLines)&#x000D;&#x000A;
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.EnsureBufferCache(IVsTextView view)&#x000D;&#x000A;
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlSource.BeginParse(Int32 line, Int32 idx, TokenInfo info, ParseReason reason, IVsTextView view, ParseResultHandler callback)&#x000D;&#x000A;
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.ViewFilter.GetDataTipText(TextSpan[] aspan, String&amp; textValue)&#x000D;&#x000A;
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.TryGetQuickInfoFromFilter(IQuickInfoSession session, TextSpan[] dataBufferTextSpan, String&amp; tipText)&#x000D;&#x000A;
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.AugmentQuickInfoSession(IQuickInfoSession session, IList`1 qiContent, ITrackingSpan&amp; applicableToSpan)&#x000D;&#x000A;
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Recalculate()&#x000D;&#x000A;
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Start()&#x000D;&#x000A;
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.DefaultQuickInfoController.OnTextView_MouseHover(Object sender, MouseHoverEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.RaiseHoverEvents()
```

After taking a few minutes to load and giving me this exception, the designer view will function but it is so slow that it is virtually unusable, and will make my whole VS session lag (It corrects itself when the designer view is closed).

I'm not experienced in XAML, so I need a way to visualize as I create. Is there a way I can fix this, or a free extension that I can use instead?

Comment: Can you provide some system information? GPU and CPU details would be fine. Also, try to perform a repair on VS, take a look here for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983433(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz (12 CPUs), ~3.5GHz, GPU: AMD FirePro W8100, I really don't think my hardware is a problem. Also, I've tried both repairing and completely reinstalling VS without any success.

Comment: Do you have any plugins/extensions enabled in Visual Studio?  If so, I'd try turning them off and see if that helps

Comment: Not a hardware problem, that's for sure. Please post VS version, Windows version, .NET Framework version installed and target .NET framework of the project. You can also try to create a new solution with a WPF project and see if the same happens

Comment: No extensions but the defaults. I have VS 2015 Community, Win 7 Professional 64-bit, .Net 4.0 and the .NET target is 4.5.2, although I just tried changing the target to 4.0 and it made no difference. I've tried creating new projects before and the problem still persists.

Comment: Head over to google and download .NET 4.6, it will likely fix the issue

Comment: Oops my mistake, I have all the .NET frameworks up to and including 4.6 by the looks of things. I tried targeting 4.6 but still no luck.

Comment: Are you targetting a normal WPF application? What happens if you create a new WPF project?

Comment: Yeah I am. Nothing really, same problem if I open up XAML design view, it just lags out until i close the design view again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96566/discussion-between-cfrozendeath-and-luke4792).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! This was done by uninstalling .NET 4.6, installing .NET 4, reinstalling Windows SDK, and then reinstalling all the necessary .NET packages.

Comment: .NET 4.6.1 has three packages and .NET 4.6.0 has three packages. All six should be removed?

Comment: Just remove everything, you can reinstall it all afterwards anyway.