# Visual Studio Community 2015 cannot load XAML

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I am able to use Visual Studio 2013 with my WPF application.

However when I try opening it with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition i got the following error:

```
Intellisense could not be initialized due to the following error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Metadata.ManagedTypeResolverService..ctor(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Package.XamlLanguagePackage.<Initialize>b__10_3(IServiceContainer c, Type t)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Package.XamlLanguagePackage.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.HostServices.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlFileInformationService.CreateFileInformationContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.GetFileContextScope(String fileName, IVsTextLines textLines, IXamlFileInformationContext& fileContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.EnsureBufferCache(IVsTextLines textLines)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.CreateSource(IVsTextLines textLines)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

I enabled the registry parameter and then got the below error:

```
Intellisense could not be initialized due to the following error: System.NotSupportedException: Required  Service 'ITypeResolverService' not found.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.HostServices.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlFileInformationService.CreateFileInformationContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.GetFileContextScope(String fileName, IVsTextLines textLines, IXamlFileInformationContext& fileContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.EnsureBufferCache(IVsTextLines textLines)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.XamlLanguageService.CreateSource(IVsTextLines textLines)
```

Where do I find and enable this service?

NOTE:

1. I have already repaired the Visual Studio without success
2. I have already uninstalled and installed the Visual Studio without success

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000496/visual-studio-2015-community-xaml-desginer-extremely-slow-to-load

Comment: That answer sounds likes like a blanket uninstall and reinstall of multiple packages. I was wondering if there a better more direct way.